# Power BI connected to API using JSON script having an Error

Tags: json, api, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to ask if anyone of you also encountered this error in Power BI

"DataFormat.Error: We found an invalid character between object key and value in the JSON input.
Details:
Value=}
Position=209176691"

Below is the complete JSON Script I'm using to connect in our API in Power BI.

= Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://bhid.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_display_value=all&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_fields=made_sla%2Cupon_reject%2Csys_updated_on%2Cchild_incidents%2Ctask_effective_number%2Cnumber%2Cresolved_by%2Csys_updated_by%2Copened_by%2Csys_created_on%2Cstate%2Cknowledge%2Cclosed_at%2Cimpact%2Cactive%2Cwork_notes_list%2Cpriority%2Copened_at%2Csys_created_by%2Cbusiness_duration%2Cresolved_at%2Ccaller_id%2Csubcategory%2Cwork_notes%2Cshort_description%2Cclose_code%2Cassignment_group%2Cdescription%2Ccalendar_duration%2Cnotify%2Csys_class_name%2Cservice_offering%2Cclose_notes%2Cclosed_by%2Csys_id%2Ccontact_type%2Creopened_by%2Cincident_state%2Curgency%2Creassignment_count%2Cactivity_due%2Cassigned_to%2Cseverity%2Ccomments%2Csla_due%2Capproval%2Ccomments_and_work_notes%2Cdue_date%2Creopen_count%2Cescalation%2Ccategory%2Chold_reason%2Cuser_input%2Ccmdb_ci%2Cbusiness_impact%2Ctime_worked%2Cwork_end%2Creopened_time%2Cwork_start%2Cbusiness_stc%2Cproblem_id%2Csys_mod_count&sysparm_limit=100000", [Headers=[Accept="application/json"]]))